# HTML POST output is null

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form in my HTML file:

```
<form action="cgi-bin/register.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="username"> New Username: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="password"> New Password: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td> </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Which, as you can see, goes to `cgi-bin/register.php`:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$encrypted_pass = md5($pass);

//... insert terrible code here ...

var_dump($user);
var_dump($pass);
?>
```

Which dumps:

```
NULL NULL
```

You guys can probably trust that I'm entering information into the form. What am I doing wrong? The only thing I could see is the wrong `method`. I have tried both `POST` and `GET`. Seems like I'm one Planck length away from getting his project to where it feels mostly finished.

**Edit:**
Tried adding a `name=""` modifier, still `NULL NULL`.

**Edit Edit:**
Fixed. Not sure what I did, but it's fixed.

Comment: You need to name your inputs.

Comment: I'd also like to add that using `md5` for passwords is no longer recommended.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm just using it for learning. This is running on my Raspberry Pi on my home network.

Comment: From what the others have given you for answers, and are all the same, they should work. Are you using it exactly as they showed you how? From your edit, it seems like it's not working for you. Did you resave/upload and refreshed your browser?

Comment: Saw your 2nd edit. Change this for your password input, from `<input type="password" id="password" name="username"/>` to `<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oops, just a typo in copying.

Comment: [See my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19919310/1415724) with explanations included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that the most probable reason that you are getting `NULL` values is that you are trying to execute PHP within `cgi-bin` which is mostly used/reserved for `.pl` or `.cgi` scripts. **(PERL/CGI)** – `.php` scripts will not execute under this folder.

Having tested your code with the fixed named inputs, and testing under `cgi-bin` produced the same results.

Move your `register.php` file outside of your `cgi-bin` and place it under `public_html` or sub-folder of your choice with the following code:

(Copy/paste exactly as shown and use inside the same folder under public html and not cgi-bin)

### HTML form

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="username"> New Username: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="password"> New Password: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td> </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

### PHP handler

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$encrypted_pass = md5($pass);

//... insert terrible code here ...

var_dump($user);
var_dump($pass);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Only named fields are passed on to `POST` request. Add `name` to the `<input>` tags:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
```

**Full Code**

```
<form action="cgi-bin/register.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="username"> New Username: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="password"> New Password: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td> </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unnamed `<input>` fields won't be passed to your `POST` request. Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
```

You'll need to make similar changes to your other `<input>`s. Note - `id` is not the same as `name`

Comment: +1 for the simple accurate explanation: *only* named fields are even sent as form data.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `name=""` attribute with the HTML form this to be correctly picked up from PHP

```
<form action="cgi-bin/register.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="username"> New Username: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="password"> New Password: </label> </td>
            <td> <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td> </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```